# PhpStorm: one gray function name amongst a bunch of yellow names, all empty, unused stubs

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a class with some empty stub functions in it right now. They are not being used anywhere, inside or outside the class. Literally just things I declared so I would remember to write them.

Curiously, one of the functions is being greyed out with the 'unused element' comment when I hover over it. I'll attach it below. I've tried rewriting the line and it doesn't change, super weird.

Anyone know what's going on?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The line is okay. But that function is never called anywhere. It helps you cleaning up code.

Comment: but neither of the other 3 functions are called anywhere. Why is it inconsistant?

Comment: When click it, what does the tooltip or "help lamp" say?

Comment: @cebo 1) If you do `File | Invalidate caches` and restart IDE -- will the issue persist? 2) Do you have *other* classes where methods with the same name exist? Can you select the name of each of these methods and use "Find in Path" for each of them -- hoe many matches they produce? It could be that some limit is reached and IDE just stops such check.

Comment: I just tried that. For a minute or so all 4 were white and then it eventually kicked in and is now the same.

Comment: What PhpStorm version are you using? It might be [this one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-54534).